# Sound stops in mid-call (incoming sound only, outgoing sound is fine)

Tags: samsung, audio

I have a bizarre problem and I don't know whether it's my phone (Samsung Galaxy S4), my Bluetooth headset (Plantronics Voyager Legend), my carrier (T-mobile) or our corporate conference call system (AT&T).

In the middle of a conference call, the sound I hear on my end will just stop. The call is still active, however, and other people on the phone call can still hear me. This has happened four or five times now. It has never happened with any of the personal phone calls on the same setup.

When it happens, if I turn off my headset and go to use the phone itself, the problem still occurs. So it makes me think that it's not related to the headset.

No one else on the conference call seems to have this problem, so maybe it's my phone rather than the conference call system. Update 4/29/2016: Just confirmed it's not the conference call system, it happened on a long call (90 minutes) direct from another phone, without involving AT&T conference calling.

I don't know what to search for on the internet. Has anyone heard of something like this happening, either to Android or to Samsung phones?